# Jury-rigging a walker for outdoor activity. Is Outdoor SE the best place?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am still drafting the details of a question, and would like to make sure it is a good fit for Outdoors (or if not, which SE might be better).

The gist of it is that my 85-year-old and mobility-limited father has asked for my assistance in brainstorming ideas to give the old ["Tim Taylor" treatment](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TimTaylorTechnology) (warning: TV tropes) to his walker, so that it will still give him some stability and support while allowing him to remove his hands momentarily to perform an action.  The actions he has in mind include yard work and geocaching- i.e. to grab a branch and lob it with pruning shears, or to pull a film can out of the branch of a tree.

In the main question, I would give some details about what exactly my father can and cannot do, the construction of the walker, and some ideas we have already tossed around.

Comment: might be ok here, you may get "better" (for some definition) answers on [lifehacks.se]

Comment: There are ingenious people on TGO, but I don't think any of them can understand what it means to be mobility limited because of age. If they have used walkers, it was temporary because of an injury. But this is a question about making the outdoors accessible to someone with a disability, and so is definitely on topic.

Comment: Question asked at Lifehacks: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/15187/19606.  Thanks for the suggestions.  (Though I reserve the right to bring the question back here if it doesn't work out there.)

Comment: This is a great question. As a person who relies on a walker (or walking-person, which is usually my husband or friend I can lean against) for many activities, and has to skip many altogether, there's definitely a need. Some of us are disabled due to injury, some to age, and some both. Being limited in our outdoor activities can be discouraging. I love that you want to help your dad improve the quality of his life! I agree that outdoor accessibility is definitely on-topic, and also an important topic!

Comment: If you don't get good answers at LH, I'd ask here. Modifying gear or techniques so people, or even dogs, can participate in things, has been addressed here. There's also a  [question](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/) about how to include people in wheelchairs while railbiking. It might be more on-topic if you focus more on the geocaching than gardening aspect, but I don't know if that matters. I did look at other sites, and couldn't find anything. I hope you get what you need!

Comment: I believe this would be on topic here, but its' reception will certainly depend on how well the question is crafted.